# Where should I store layouts for 480x800?

Tags: android

I've got some layouts for 480x800 Android devices. I put it in layout-hdpi folder, but when I launch my application using 480x800 Android device I see other layout (universal layout for other devices). How can I fix it?

Comment: How about in `/res/layout-800x480` folder ?

Comment: 480x800 doesn't mean HDPI - normal sized phones at that resolution are HDPI, but some of the older / lower spec tablets have that resolution over a much large screen. What device did you test it on?

Comment: Hey Funk, Is it possible that normal sized phones can have a resolution LDPI, MDPI or smaller?

Comment: Whenever I set background in an activity on GRAND DUOS, image just doesn't shows up! What to do any idea? :/

Answer (score 1):

For testing on Samsung grand make a folder in res named as layout-sw360dp and put all the layout there. Hope it will work